If $z_1+z_2+z_3=z_1z_2z_3$, then $z_1$, $z_2$ and $z_3$ cannot lie all above the real axis.
I am trying to solve the following problem:

If $z_1$, $z_2$ and $z_3$ are complex numbers such that $z_1+z_2+z_3=z_1z_2z_3$, then $z_1$, $z_2$ and $z_3$ cannot lie all above the real axis.

It is a problem in Limits by Alan Beardon that I have been self-studying. I have been stuck on this problem for quite some time.
Writing $z_j=x_j+iy_j$ with $x_j,y_j$ real numbers for $j\in\{1,2,3\}$, we have
$$
z_1+z_2+z_3 = (x_1+x_2+x_3)+i(y_1+y_2+y_2)
$$
and
$$
z_1z_2z_3 = (x_1x_2x_3-x_1y_2y_3-y_1x_2y_3-y_1y_2x_3)
+i(x_1x_2y_3+x_1y_2x_3+y_1x_2x_3-y_1y_2y_3)
$$
so $x_1+x_2+x_3=x_1x_2x_3-x_1y_2y_3-y_1x_2y_3-y_1y_2x_3$ and $y_1+y_2+y_3=x_1x_2y_3+x_1y_2x_3+y_1x_2x_3-y_1y_2y_3$.
But I am not sure how it can help to show that at least one of the $y_j's$ is not positive. Most of the other problems in this section are about various forms of triangular inequality, but I don't know how to use it here.
Any idea?

Assume that $z_1$ and $z_2$ have positive imaginary parts then
$$z_3=\frac{z_1+z_2}{z_1z_2-1}=\frac{|z_2|^2\bar z_1+|z_1|^2\bar z_2-z_1-z_2}{|z_1z_2-1|^2}$$
which is the sum of complex numbers with negative imaginary part and therefore $z_3$ has negative imaginary part.

Look at the arguments (I constrain them to the interval $[0,2\pi)$),
If $z_1z_2z_3=z_1+z_2+z_3$, and they all have positive imaginary parts, then

the arguments of all three are in the interval $(0,\pi)$,
the argument of their average is also in that interval, and exceeds the smallest argument of the three numbers, and is also smaller than the largest of the three arguments,
but the argument of the product is either larger than any of the three, and (in case it wraps around $2\pi$) less than any of three $+2\pi$.


If they were, then $t_k : = \frac{x_k-i}{x_k+i} \in D$ the open unit disk, and $1+t_1 t_2 t_3=0$, contradiction.
$\bf{Added:}$
Let's see how we can do the same for $n$ complex numbers $z_k$. Assume all of them are in the upper half plane.  We have
$$|\prod_{k=1}^n (z_k +  i)| > |\prod_{k=1}^n (z_k -  i)|$$
since $|z_k -(- i) | > |z_k -  i|$ for all $1\le k \le n$. We conclude we cannot have the equality
$$\prod_{k=1}^n (z_k +  i)+\prod_{k=1}^n (z_k -  i) = 0$$
that is :
$$s_n -  s_{n-2} +  s_{n-4} - \cdots \ne 0$$
where $s_m = \sum z_1 \cdots z_m$.
For instance, for $n=5$,  we get: if $z_1$, $\ldots$, $z_5$ satisfy
$$s_5 - s_3 + s_1 = 0$$
then not all of them can be in the upper half plane.

$x_k=\frac{1+t_k}{1-t_k}i$ and I checked. I dont know Grobned basis.

@Bob Dobbs: Yes.  Groebner bases would be useful when one could not express $x_k$ in terms of $t_k$.
